# Gdx-Pay iOS store, can't find product info

Tags: ios, libgdx, app-store, robovm

I have a working implementation of gdx-pay for Android using the Google App Store. I did that following this: https://bitbucket.org/just4phil/gdxpayexample/src/.

I am now trying to get it working on iOS, but can't find any docs on how to do that. In the project linked above there is no "ios app store" or any changes made to the ios-project. Does anyone have a link to an example working with ios?

I tried some stuff out and got this far:

IOSResolver:

```
public class IOSResolver extends PlatformResolver {

    public IOSResolver(MyGdxGame myGame) {
        super(myGame);

        PurchaseManagerConfig config = myGame.purchaseManagerConfig;
        initializeIAP(null, myGame.purchaseObserver, config);
        installIAP();
    }
```

IOSLauncher:

```
@Override
    protected IOSApplication createApplication() {
        IOSApplicationConfiguration config = new IOSApplicationConfiguration();
        config.orientationLandscape = false;
        config.orientationPortrait = true;
        config.useCompass = false;
        config.useAccelerometer = false;
        game = new MyGdxGame(new IOSPlatform());
        return new IOSApplication(game, config);
    }

@Override
    public boolean didFinishLaunching(UIApplication application, UIApplicationLaunchOptions launchOptions) {
        boolean finished = super.didFinishLaunching(application, launchOptions);
        game.setPlatformResolver(new IOSResolver(game));
        return finished;
    }
```

Core:

```
// ---- IAP: define products ---------------------
        purchaseManagerConfig = new PurchaseManagerConfig();
        purchaseManagerConfig.addOffer(new Offer().setType(OfferType.ENTITLEMENT).setIdentifier(ios_productId));
```

This gives me the error:

```
[GdxPay/AppleIOS] Requesting product info for test.product.id
2017-02-20 16:58:58.089803 IOSLauncher[5611:2144625] [info] gdx-pay: calls purchasemanager.purchase()
[GdxPay/AppleIOS] Error purchasing product (wrong product info count returned: 0)!
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error purchasing product (wrong product info count returned: 0)!
    at com.scene2d.space_camp.MyGdxGame$1.handlePurchaseError(MyGdxGame.java)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.pay.ios.apple.PurchaseManageriOSApple$AppleProductsDelegatePurchase.didReceiveResponse(PurchaseManageriOSApple.java)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.pay.ios.apple.PurchaseManageriOSApple$AppleProductsDelegatePurchase.$cb$productsRequest$didReceiveResponse$(PurchaseManageriOSApple.java)
    at org.robovm.apple.uikit.UIApplication.main(UIApplication.java)
    at org.robovm.apple.uikit.UIApplication.main(UIApplication.java)
    at com.scene2d.tut.IOSLauncher.main(IOSLauncher.java)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error purchasing product (wrong product info count returned: 0)!
    ... 5 more
```

I registered the app on iTunes Connect and set up a product. However I did not post binaries, do I need to for testing IAP? It shows this message in iTunes Connect:

> Your first In-App Purchase must be submitted with a new app version.
>   Select it from the app’s In-App Purchases section and click Submit.
>
> Once your binary has been uploaded and your first In-App Purchase has
>   been submitted for review, additional In-App Purchases can be
>   submitted using the table below.

Is there no way to test without uploading the actual app?

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?

Comment: @grimrader22 I did not, but I came to the conclusion that you need to setup a bunch of stuff (sign contract etc) in itunesConnect in order to test. So I am assuming that is why.

Comment: that was indeed the issue. Once my Paid Apps agreement had processed the IAP became available in the app.

Comment: What exactly was processed? Did it needed Apple team review before you can use it?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and was seeing the same error message.

I think the two keys to getting your IAPs work are the following:

1. Use a real device for testing, not an emulated one.
2. Sign in with a sandbox account, not a real one.

Create your sandbox account on itunesconnect. 
Build your app and install it onto your ipad/iphone using xcode.
On your device, go into settings and logout.  This is important.
Run your app and make a purchase. You will be prompted to login. Use your sandbox account.

I did this and it worked.